# I am unable to host my heroku app on my custom owned domain managed by Infomaniak (www.infomaniak.com)

Tags: heroku, custom-domain

Currently I am using Herokuapp to host my web application which is basically a personal website. With the default heroku given domain, its working properly. But whenever I am addiding the custom domain to my app (also adding CNAME for DNS target in my DNS registrar (which is Infomaniak.com), it does not work. I have tried everything (also waiting for more than a day to check if the app shows up in my custom domain) but was unable to do it until now. I have tried support from Infomaniak as well but did not work. Did anyone else face this issue and can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?